# What timezone is StartDate extractParam is using when doing an ExactTarget Api ExtractRequest?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am doing an ExactTarget Api ExtractRequest, and specifying a start and end date as parameters as well. I would like to know in which timezone are my date params translated, and where the timezone is specified in the ET account?

Thanks,
Erisa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timezones are all set to Central Standard Time and Daylight savings is not observed.

You can update the timezone in the Administration -> Account -> General Settings.

Setting the timezone aids with all UI translations into your local time - but the API will still operate in CST.

Comment: Users also have a timezone level setting.