# How do I filter for Events between two dates?

Tags: soap-api, fuel-sdk

I am using the Ruby FuelSDK, and set my filter to:

```
  filter = {
    :LeftOperand => {
      'Property' => 'EventDate',
      'SimpleOperator' => 'greaterThan',
      'DateValue' => fromDate
    }, 
    :LogicalOperator => 'AND',
    :RightOperand => {
      'Property' => 'EventDate',
      'SimpleOperator' => 'lessThan',
      'DateValue' => toDate
    }
  }
```

The error message returned seems nonsensical:

> Error: Invalid argument for the equals operator. Filter array cannot be null.

Is it possible to search for events between two dates?

If it helps, SOAP debugging showed this:

```
<tns:Filter xsi:type="tns:SimpleFilterPart"><tns:leftOperand><tns:Property>EventDate</tns:Property><tns:SimpleOperator>greaterThan</tns:SimpleOperator><tns:DateValue>2014-04-26T13:00:00.000</tns:DateValue></tns:leftOperand><tns:logicalOperator>AND</tns:logicalOperator><tns:rightOperand><tns:Property>EventDate</tns:Property><tns:SimpleOperator>lessThan</tns:SimpleOperator><tns:DateValue>2014-04-27T13:00:00.000</tns:DateValue></tns:rightOperand></tns:Filter>
```

which looks ok, and the response is:

```
<OverallStatus>Error: Invalid argument for the equals operator. Filter array cannot be null.</OverallStatus>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why the above doesn't work, but I have succeeded with the `between` operator:

```
filter = {
    'Property' => 'EventDate',
    'SimpleOperator' => 'between',
    'DateValue' => [fromDate.utc.iso8601, toDate.utc.iso8601]
  }
```

Note that while we query in UTC as above, you may find that the EventDate is returned in Central Standard Timezone (no DST), as per: [What timezone is StartDate extractParam is using when doing an ExactTarget Api ExtractRequest?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63466/what-timezone-is-startdate-extractparam-is-using-when-doing-an-exacttarget-api-e)